# Sort Div by attribute - asc or desc

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote the code to sort divs by price attribute. But will not work correctly. Who can help?
So you can see in the code [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/totaldesign/2xh4LLgr/2/)

**Js:**

```
    $(".link-sort-list").on("click",function(e){
    var $list = $('#sort-list');
    var $productList = $('div.product-box',$list);
    $productList.sort(function(a, b){
        var keyA = $(a).attr("price");
        var keyB = $(b).attr("price");

        if($(this).hasClass('asc')){
            console.log("asc");
            return (parseInt(keyA) > parseInt(keyB)) ? 1 : 0;
        } else {
            console.log("desc");
            return (parseInt(keyA) < parseInt(keyB)) ? 1 : 0;
        }
    });
    $.each($productList, function(index, row){
        $list.append(row);
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Daniel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34704217/5460631), instead of logical comparison (`<`, `>`), use subtraction (`-`).

The "compare" function in `sort(compare)` must take two arguments `a` and `b`. The return value of the `compare` function needs to return a value based on these two parameters:

1. Return *greater than 0* if `a` is greater than `b`
2. Return *0* if `a` equals `b`
3. Return *less than 0* if `a` is less than `b`

For details see the answer ["How does sort function work in JavaScript"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567941/how-does-sort-function-work-in-javascript-along-with-compare-function), explained in a nice way.

```
$(".link-sort-list").on("click",function(e){
    var $this = $(this);
    var $list = $('#sort-list');
    var $productList = $('div.product-box',$list);
    var order = $this.hasClass('asc');
    console.log(order);
    $productList.sort(function(a, b){
        var keyA = $(a).attr("price");
        var keyB = $(b).attr("price");
        return order ? (parseInt(keyA) - parseInt(keyB)) : (parseInt(keyB) - parseInt(keyA));
    });
    $.each($productList, function(index, row){
       $list.append(row);
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

https://jsfiddle.net/danvim/2xh4LLgr/3/

You need to remember `$this` changes in different function scope.

Do this to set the target:

```
var $this = $(this)
```

Updated code:

```
$(".link-sort-list").on("click",function(e){
    var $this = $(this);  //<--
    var $list = $('#sort-list');
    var $productList = $('div.product-box',$list);
    $productList.sort(function(a, b){
        var keyA = $(a).attr("price");
        var keyB = $(b).attr("price");

        if($this.hasClass('asc')){ //<--
            console.log("asc");
            return (parseInt(keyA) > parseInt(keyB)) ? 1 : 0;
        } else {
            console.log("desc");
            return (parseInt(keyA) < parseInt(keyB)) ? 1 : 0;
        }
    });
    $.each($productList, function(index, row){
        $list.append(row);
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

### Final Solution

But I would recommend putting the checking of `$this` outside the `sort` method. Also, you wouldn't need the shorthand-if, just return the Boolean value will do.

So I would simplify it like so: https://jsfiddle.net/danvim/2xh4LLgr/5/

This will run quicker because the checking for `.asc` only happens once whereas your original function will check once for every item to be compared.

```
$(".link-sort-list").on("click",function(e){
    var $this = $(this);
    var $list = $('#sort-list');
    var $productList = $('div.product-box',$list);
    var order = $this.hasClass('asc');
    console.log(order);
    $productList.sort(function(a, b){
        var keyA = $(a).attr("price");
        var keyB = $(b).attr("price");
            return order ? (parseInt(keyA) > parseInt(keyB)) : (parseInt(keyA) < parseInt(keyB));
    });
    $.each($productList, function(index, row){
        $list.append(row);
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Click on ASC or Desc several times. With each click, divs are sorted differently!! Should sorting must be done at once?

Comment: My problem is that, Sorting data do not be properly.

Comment: @AliTD I do not quite understand the problem, did the latter link have the problem? Can you describe it with example? I tried the fiddle and items are sorted properly.