# JS code understanding

Tags: javascript

```
var arr = [
"rohan",
"markandeya",
"hanumante",
"sapan",
"Ritesh"
];

Array.prototype.longest=function() {
return this.sort(
  function(a,b) {  
    if (a.length > b.length) return -1;
    if (a.length < b.length) return 1;
      return 0
  }
)[0];
}
alert(arr.longest());
```

Need to understand the above code line by line. I exactly didn't get function(a,b) part can any one explain it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: a,b just pop from anywhere. Can you check the code again?

Comment: You should probably start with something more basic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does sort function work in JavaScript, along with compare function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567941/how-does-sort-function-work-in-javascript-along-with-compare-function)

Comment: Although you already accepted my answer, I just realized I missed a part of what the code did, that is very relevant. I've edited my answer to include this part, at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var arr = [
"rohan",
"markandeya",
"hanumante",
"sapan",
"Ritesh"
];
```

This defines an array of strings and assigns it to the variable `arr`

```
Array.prototype.longest=function() {
  return this.sort(
    function(a,b) {  
      if (a.length > b.length) return -1;
      if (a.length < b.length) return 1;
        return 0
    }
  )[0];
}
```

This creates a new function `longest` and adds it to the `prototype` of `Array`. In short, adding to the prototype makes the new function available to any object with type `Array` in your application. E.g., you can now call `arr.longest()`  as seen in the last line of your code: (because `arr` is of type `Array`)

`alert(arr.longest());`

Now for the interesting part. `Array.prototype` already contains a `sort` function. This function expects a parameter that is a `compare function`. In other words, **you have to define HOW items in the array are sorted by describing how two items are compared to see which one comes first in the sort process**. This function is here defined as:

```
   function(a,b) {  
      if (a.length > b.length) return -1;
      if (a.length < b.length) return 1;
        return 0
    }
```

Now, `Array.prototype.sort`, as I said, expects a sort callback. This callback is expected to return either 0, 1 or -1 to indicate the order in which two items (here named `a` and `b`, but these names are arbitrary) should be sorted.

It seems from reading this function, that the items are sorted by a property `length`. Since your array `arr` is an array of strings, and strings have a `length` property, this works just fine.

So why 0, 1 or -1? From [MDN: Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort): (click link for more info)

> If compareFunction is supplied, the array elements are sorted
>   according to the return value of the compare function. If a and b are
>   two elements being compared, then:
>
> If compareFunction(a, b) is less than 0, sort a to a lower index than
>   b, i.e. a comes first.
>
> If compareFunction(a, b) returns 0, leave a and
>   b unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all
>   different elements. Note: the ECMAscript standard does not guarantee
>   this behaviour, and thus not all browsers (e.g. Mozilla versions
>   dating back to at least 2003) respect this.
>
> If compareFunction(a, b)
>   is greater than 0, sort b to a lower index than a.
>
> compareFunction(a,
>   b) must always return the same value when given a specific pair of
>   elements a and b as its two arguments. If inconsistent results are
>   returned then the sort order is undefined.

### Edit

I missed some details about the code that are important to mention:

The function `longest` does not just sort the array. I read over this part when I first posted my answer. If we look at the following snippet:

```
return this.sort(
  function(a,b) {  
    if (a.length > b.length) return -1;
    if (a.length < b.length) return 1;
      return 0
  }
)[0];
```

Pay attention to the `return` and `[0]` parts. As I explained, `this.sort` will sort the array `arr` based on string length (longest first). Then, the first item of the **result** of the sort function is taken by `[0]`. The first item is the longest, because the array was sorted. This is then **returned** by the function `longest`. So in effect, the `longest` function returns the longest string in an array, by first sorting that array by length and returning the first item (with index 0) in that sorted array.

Comment: var arr = [
    "1----",
    "2 ----",
    "3 --",
 "48883632634322178942",
    "4888-sharukh-khan",
    "sharukh ----"
];
var longest = '';

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if ( arr[i].length > longest.length ) {
        longest = arr[i];
    }
} 

alert(longest);    We can do by this way also the easy way to find the longest string in an array.

Comment: Yes, there are multiple ways to solve this problem. Yours is very straight forward, but I think the GOOD thing about the code you originally posted is that it uses existing functions, instead of 're-inventing the wheel'. Do note that sorting the whole array, just to find the longest item, seems overkill and should NOT be done if performance is a concern. In that case, your solution posted in the comment is probably better. Also, do note that many consider it BAD practise to edit the prototype of existing types (like adding 'longest' to Array.prototype).