# how to sort small and capital letter in js or jquery

Tags: javascript, sorting

If have an array like this

var tab = ['1185 Design','3 D Exhibits','44Doors',
'4Concepts','ABC Data','acceleration'];

I want to sort it so that small letter 'a' element comes before capital letter 'A' element.
Thanks.

Comment: See [*How does sort function work in JavaScript, along with compare function*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567941/how-does-sort-function-work-in-javascript-along-with-compare-function).

Comment: And should "zebra" come before "Antelope"? (Your example only has the same word with different capitalisation.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting an array of JavaScript objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Comment: I want a-z to come first  before A-Z

Answer (score 2):

Your array :

```
var tab = ["Animal","123",  "animal"]
```

Sort function :

```
tab.sort(function(a,b){return a.localeCompare(b); })
```

OUTPUT :

```
["123", "animal", "Animal"]
```

[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/wmj7yoah/)

Comment: Hi , I need it like a-z comes first then A-Z
example : apple,APPLE,bat ,Button

Comment: How you want it sort your exemple ? apple,APPLE,bat ,Button

Comment: You want apple, bat, APPLE, Button ?

Comment: No , a A together then b B like this apple,APPLE,bat ,Button .. always small letter before capital

Comment: My code does it... I don't understand what's the problem

Comment: if I have these elements

1185 Design,3 D Exhibits,44Doors,4Concepts,ABC Data,acceleration,Accent Electronic,Acme Computer Components,Acorn Marketing,Ad verum,Adacado,Adobe Systems,AdPeopleWorldWide,Advania,Affiniti,Afghanistan,Agua Marketing,aimClear,Albania,Algeria,Allbound,AMD,AMI Communications,Amsterdam Worldwide,Andorra,Angola,Anguilla,Aniden Interactive . that acceleration element should come before 'A' element

Comment: I tried your code on the above example small letter acceleration element is not coming before ABC Data element