# I can't understand how " return " value affect for sort

Tags: javascript, compare

```
function compare(a, b) {
  if (a is less than b by some ordering criterion) {
  // how minus 1 will affect to sort? how sort will understand this value? 
 return -1; 
  }
  if (a is greater than b by the ordering criterion) {
    return 1;
  }
  // a must be equal to b
  return 0;
}
```

or in the next example:

```
var numbers = [4, 2, 5, 1, 3];
numbers.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
});
console.log(numbers);

// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I know only know "true" or "false" , which are 1 and 0. And how compare and sort wiil   understand what is that (1 , -1 , 0) and how sort to make permutation using these values?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567941/how-does-sort-function-work-in-javascript-along-with-compare-function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does sort function work in JavaScript, along with compare function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567941/how-does-sort-function-work-in-javascript-along-with-compare-function)

Answer (score 1):

The `Array.prototype.sort` function expects the callback to return a number, not a boolean (e.g., not `true` or `false`). It uses the number to know what the ordering of the two entries it gave the sort callback should be. You can imagine the logic within `sort` being along these lines:

```
result = callback(a, b);
if (result < 0) {
    // Make sure `a` is before `b`
} else if (result > 0) {
    // Make sure `b` is before `a`
} else {
    // It doesn't matter which is first, they're equivalent
}
```

As you can see, `true` and `false` aren't involved (except as the result of `<` or `>`).

And that means that if `a` and `b` are numbers and the callback returns `a - b`, it will sort numerically, because if `a` is less than `b`, the result will be negative; if `a` is greater than `b`, the result will be positive; and if they're the same, the result is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) describe this pretty well:

> **arr.sort(compareFunction)**
>
> If compareFunction is supplied, the array elements are sorted
>   according to the return value of the compare function. If a and b are
>   two elements being compared, then:
>
> - If compareFunction(a, b) is less than 0, sort a to a lower index than    b, i.e. a comes first.
> - If compareFunction(a, b) returns 0, leave a    and b unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect    to all
>     different elements. Note: the ECMAscript standard does not
>     guarantee this behaviour, and thus not all browsers (e.g. Mozilla
>     versions dating back to at least 2003) respect this.
> - If    compareFunction(a, b) is greater than 0, sort b to a lower index than    a. compareFunction(a, b) must always return the same
>     value when given    a specific pair of elements a and b as its two
>     arguments. If    inconsistent results are returned then the sort order
>     is undefined.

Comment: Thank you, it really helped me