# How does this array sorting function actually work?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I was working on some coding challenges for practice and came across one that stumped me. Reading an article about it, I came across the answer, which I cannot understand. The challenge was to create a function that sorts an array of integers in ascending order and returns it. The function is as follows:

```
function sortAscending(arr) {
    return arr.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a - b;
    });
}
```

What I can't understand is how sorting using the compare function `return a - b` actually works. If I have an array of random integers and I take a calculator and apply that arithmetic operation to each, it does not result in an array that is sorted in ascending order, it results in a completely different array. So that tells me I must be completely misunderstanding how this work. Anyone care to explain this to someone with basically no computer science knowledge?

Comment: Well, the `sort` function is actually doing the sorting. The inner function is a comparator. If you subtract two numbers, and the result is negative, the first number is smaller than the second. Look up how `sort` uses the function given to it.

Comment: I suggest getting a piece of paper and pencil and working through a small example by hand. Be sure to read the documentation of `sort()` so that you understand how the return value of the callback function is used.

Comment: Accepted [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567941/how-does-sort-function-work-in-javascript-along-with-compare-function) would be a great starting point

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does sort function work in JavaScript, along with compare function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567941/how-does-sort-function-work-in-javascript-along-with-compare-function)

Comment: i once wrote a long answer on quora .maybe it will help https://www.quora.com/Can-somebody-explain-sort-function-with-a-compare-function-as-a-parameter-in-Javascript/answer/Ashish-Singh-348

Answer (score 3):

Your compare function `(a,b) => a-b` is telling the `sort` function how to sort.  In other words, it tells `sort` how to compare two values at a time.  Internally, `sort` applies your compare function repeatedly until it comes up with the sorted results.

if the return value is less than zero, a should be sorted to an index less than b (so a is placed in the array before b)

If the return value is greater than zero, a should be sorted to an index greater than b.

If the return value IS zero, then the order should remain unchanged.

Any `undefined` value (in either a or b) gets sorted to the end of the array w/o actually calling the compare function.

This is well documented on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: You’re correct. This is how the sort method in many programming languages works.