# Why ExtJS sorter function is obliged to return -1/0/1

Tags: extjs, comparator

[Ext.util.Sorter.sorterFn](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.4.0/modern/Ext.util.Sorter.html#cfg-sorterFn) return value is restricted to `-1/0/1`. Also I found mentions of this expectation in comments in the source code.
Why not just to return `any negative number/0/any positive number`?

I am not asking why it is good to have a comparator that conviniently returns `-1/0/1`.
I am asking why authors of the framework decided to limit us with `-1/0/1` even while JS itself allows `any negative number/0/any positive number` in its comparator callbacks.

Comment: It is a very basic sorting mechanism. It decides whether from ordering point of view if the two input values are equal (0), or the first precedes (-1) or follows (1) the second parameter. What would other numbers mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does sort function work in JavaScript, along with compare function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567941/how-does-sort-function-work-in-javascript-along-with-compare-function)

Comment: @PeterKoltai the question is about why we are stuck to `-1/0/1`, why not simply `any negative number/0/any positive number`.

Comment: @AndreyGodyaev I think it is simply an efficiency consideration.

Comment: @PeterKoltai the most efficient comparator for numbers is `(a, b) => a - b`, hence it can't be an efficiency consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you could use any number as long as they have an order, like -1/0/1 or -12/0/200.

Here is an example:

```
            sorters: [{
                sorterFn: function(person1, person2) {
                    let lhs = person1.data.name,
                        rhs = person2.data.name;

                    return (lhs > rhs) ? 200 : (lhs === rhs ? 0 : -12);
                }
            }],
```

And here the fiddle, which shows the results [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3ge5)

!!! First of all you might want to consider the comments from PeterKoltai and aaandri98 !!!

Further - to keep your code readable for everyone (now and in the future) you might want to go with static numbers, that are -1/0/1.

And the rule is: one has to be negativ and one positive, because of the part inside Ext.Array.binarySearch

```
if (comparison >= 0) {
    begin = middle + 1;
} else if (comparison < 0) {
    end = middle - 1;
}
```

Comment: You certainly can't replace zero with any value, [Ext.Array.binarySearch](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.2/api/Ext.Array.html#method-binarySearch) expects from sorters zero on equality.

Comment: You are right. Updated the post and added a part about Ext.Array.binarySearch. Thanks