# Sorting method why difference return

Tags: javascript, sorting

Why when sorting we do something like this?

```
employees.sort(function(a, b){
 return a.age-b.age
}
```

Why it is enough to return the difference between 2 values?

Comment: Add the language tag.

Comment: Whatever in many languages You use this way, this one is JS

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does Javascript's sort() work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494713/how-does-javascripts-sort-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If function returns positive value it means that a object is bigger.
If function returns 0 it means that a is equal to b.
If function return negative value it means that b is bigger.

It's enough to compare all elements in collection, the only information it needs, it's how compare any two elements.

Comment: Thanks a lot Zbigniew, I will accept Your answer as fast as Ill be allowed to. 

Dziękuję!