# What sort algorithm is NodeJS 14.4.0 using for Array.sort on array of four elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting

I don't believe this is a duplicate of this
[How does Javascript's sort() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494713/how-does-javascripts-sort-work)

```
let arr = [3, 4, 2, 1];
arr.sort((second,first) => {
  console.log([first, second]);
  if (first>second) {
    return -1; // switch them
  }
  return 0; // don't switch them

});
console.log(arr);
```

This returns

```
[ 3, 4 ]
[ 4, 2 ]
[ 4, 2 ] <---- Why is this output twice?
[ 3, 2 ]
[ 3, 1 ]
[ 2, 1 ]
[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
```

I am trying to figure out what algorithm NodeJS (14.4.0) is using for Array.sort with my input?

Comment: Your sort callback could cause inconsistent results because you are returning `0` when `second > first`. Try adding a `else if (second > first) { return 1 }`.

Comment: Also, it's pure evil to name the first parameter as `second` and second parameter as `first`. I was wondering why the `sort` was working the wrong way :)

Comment: Related: [Sorting in JavaScript: Should every compare function have a “return 0” statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20883421)

Comment: @adiga also relevant: [Sorting in JavaScript: Shouldn't returning a boolean be enough for a comparison function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24080785)

Comment: @adiga I think that was because the order of the items in the array. Not my code originally :)

Answer (score 2):

As a note in this [post](https://v8.dev/features/stable-sort), the v8 engine apparently uses Timsort for sorting:

https://v8.dev/blog/array-sort#timsort

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by [@Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66261473/what-sort-algorithm-is-nodejs-14-4-0-using-for-array-sort-on-array-of-four-eleme/66261623#66261623), the V8 engine has implemented `Array.prototype.sort()` with [TimSort](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/main/third_party/v8/builtins/array-sort.tq#L5C71-L5C78), which itself uses [BinaryInsertionSort](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/main/third_party/v8/builtins/array-sort.tq#L510). I don't know much about the V8 Torque language, so the following behaviour that I have experimented, I could not verify it in the linked .tq file...

```js
let arr = [3, 4, 2, 1];
arr.sort((a, b) => {
  console.log(a, b);
  if (b > a) {
    return -1; // switch them
  }
  return 0; // don't switch them
});
console.log(arr);
```

Here how it goes:

```
// original array:
// 3 4 2 1
// insertion sort works by comparing items backwards
// so in the first iteration:
// (i = 1) a = 4
// (j = i - 1 = 0) b = 3
// console.log returns 4, 3
// your compareFn returns 0 in this case, so no swapping, elements are considered in order as per your compareFn
// you can also notice that the input array will be mutated only after the last iteration, as the implementation uses a copy internally to work with
// at the end of this first iteration, this internal array is still:
// 3 4 2 1
// next iteration (i++):
// (i = 2) a = 2
// (j = i - 1 = 1) b = 4
// console.log returns 2, 4
// now, as per your compareFn, since it returns -1, both elements are considered not in order
// then something happens that I could not verify in the implementation: instead of decreasing j by 1 to find the index where `a` should be inserted like in the js example given [here][4], as soon as the first comparison fails (when a negative value is returned for the first time by the compareFn when comparing elements) the algorithm switches to a dichotomous logic on all the items in the internal array (sorted, then) before the current i index (representing the value `a` to reorder by insertion). So this includes element at current index j.
// next iteration (dichotomy starts):
// since there are 2 elements before `a`, it compares it with `b = 4` again)
// (i = 2) a = 2
// (j = 1) b = 4 (dichotomy logic: j = Math.ceil((i-1)/2)
// console.log returns 2, 4
// compareFn returns -1, so `b` and `a` not in order (already compared in this case but it is a trivial case where j points to the same element again by dichotomy because the original array is so small)
// next iteration:
// (i = 2) a = 2
// (j = 0) b = 3 (dichotomy logic again: j = prev_j - Math.ceil((i-1-prev_j)/2))
// console.log returns 2, 3
// compareFn returns -1, so still not in order
// j = 0 so all the elements before `a` are right shifted in the internal array and a is inserted at index 0:
// 2 3 4 1
// next iteration (i++):
// (i = 3) a = 1
// (j = 1) b = 3 (dichotomy logic: j = Math.ceil((i-1)/2)
// console.log returns 1, 3
// compareFn returns -1, so not in order
// next iteration:
// (i = 3) a = 1
// (j = 0) b = 2 (dichotomy logic again: j = prev_j - Math.ceil((i-1-prev_j)/2))
// console.log returns 1, 2
// compareFn returns -1, so not in order
// j = 0 so all the elements before `a` are right shifted in the internal array and a is inserted at index 0:
// 1 2 3 4
// done
```

If you used a bigger array, say `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, -1]` you would see the dichotomy logic better:

```
-1 15
-1 8
-1 4
-1 2
-1 1
-1 0
```

This is true if the length of the array is < 64: in theses cases, no merge algorithm is involved. See [here](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/main/third_party/v8/builtins/array-sort.tq#L1185).

For bigger arrays, it is bit more complicated...